# OS X Server Mavericks stuck on "Preparing Services"

Tags: macos, install, server.app

I am trying to install OS X Server app version 3 on Mavericks system. I tried everything, including manually deleting all server app files and making clean install, but nothing works. Whenever I start the installation process, it sticks on "Preparing services". The app keeps respond, but no HDD activity is visible at all. Does somebody encountered the same problem?

Comment: What does the log say? (/Library/Logs/ServerSetup.log)

Answer (score 1):

Try resetting Server.app permissions:

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Applications/Server.app
sudo chmod -R g+rx,o+rx /Applications/Server.app
```

This has been discussed on this Apple Support Communities thread:

- https://discussions.apple.com/message/24122772#24122772

Comment: I already tried this, but it didn't help. Will try again.

Answer (score 0):

As I am advising you, which you have done already after removing server.app setting. Have you re-download the same app from Apple site? after all this- have you  restart your configuration? If no then it might be the reason else yes then you can take a help by visiting here-

Read More: https://support.apple.com/en-in/HT200271